# Class constant dictionary in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm building a module that has a class variable dictionary:

```
class CodonUsageTable:
        CODON_DICT={'TTT': 0, 'TTC': 0, 'TTA': 0, 'TTG': 0, 'CTT': 0,
        'CTC': 0, 'CTA': 0, 'CTG': 0, 'ATT': 0, 'ATC': 0,
        'ATA': 0, 'ATG': 0, 'GTT': 0, 'GTC': 0, 'GTA': 0,
        'GTG': 0, 'TAT': 0, 'TAC': 0, 'TAA': 0, 'TAG': 0,
        'CAT': 0, 'CAC': 0, 'CAA': 0, 'CAG': 0, 'AAT': 0,
        'AAC': 0, 'AAA': 0, 'AAG': 0, 'GAT': 0, 'GAC': 0,
        'GAA': 0, 'GAG': 0, 'TCT': 0, 'TCC': 0, 'TCA': 0,
        'TCG': 0, 'CCT': 0, 'CCC': 0, 'CCA': 0, 'CCG': 0,
        'ACT': 0, 'ACC': 0, 'ACA': 0, 'ACG': 0, 'GCT': 0,
        'GCC': 0, 'GCA': 0, 'GCG': 0, 'TGT': 0, 'TGC': 0,
        'TGA': 0, 'TGG': 0, 'CGT': 0, 'CGC': 0, 'CGA': 0,
        'CGG': 0, 'AGT': 0, 'AGC': 0, 'AGA': 0, 'AGG': 0,

#Other code

        def __init__(self,seqobj):
                '''Creates codon table for a given Bio.seq object.i
                The only argument is Bio.Seq object with DNA
                Currently assumes seq to be DNA, RNA support to be added later'''
                dnaseq=str(seqobj)
                self.usage_table=CodonUsageTable.CODON_DICT.deepcopy()#instance of table
```

The last line must make a copy of class dictionary to store instance data in it, but it throws

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./codon_usage.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.usage_table=CodonUsageTable.CODON_DICT.deepcopy()#instance of codon usage table
NameError: global name 'CODON_DICT' is not defined
```

So does `self.CODON_DICT`, `CODON_DICT` or `codon_usage.CodonUsageTable.CODON_DICT`, when called from `__init__`. Dictionary is defined:

```
>>>import codon_usage
>>> codon_usage.CodonUsageTable.CODON_DICT
{'GCT': 0, 'GGA': 0, 'TTA': 0, 'GAT': 0, 'TTC': 0, 'TTG': 0, 'AGT': 0, 'GCG': 0, 'AGG': 0, 'GCC': 0, 'CGA': 0, 'GCA': 0, 'GGC': 0, 'GAG': 0, 'GAA': 0, 'TTT': 0, 'GAC': 0, 'TAT': 0, 'CGC': 0, 'TGT': 0, 'TCA': 0, 'GGG': 0, 'TCC': 0, 'ACG': 0, 'TCG': 0, 'TAG': 0, 'TAC': 0, 'TAA': 0, 'ACA': 0, 'TGG': 0, 'TCT': 0, 'TGA': 0, 'TGC': 0, 'CTG': 0, 'CTC': 0, 'CTA': 0, 'ATG': 0, 'ATA': 0, 'ATC': 0, 'AGA': 0, 'CTT': 0, 'ATT': 0, 'GGT': 0, 'AGC': 0, 'ACT': 0, 'CGT': 0, 'GTT': 0, 'CCT': 0, 'AAG': 0, 'CGG': 0, 'AAC': 0, 'CAT': 0, 'AAA': 0, 'CCC': 0, 'GTC': 0, 'CCA': 0, 'GTA': 0, 'CCG': 0, 'GTG': 0, 'ACC': 0, 'CAA': 0, 'CAC': 0, 'AAT': 0, 'CAG': 0}        'GGT': 0, 'GGC': 0, 'GGA': 0, 'GGG': 0}
```

Comment: `s/CodonUsageTable.CODON_DICT/CODON_DICT/g` inside the class itself

Comment: Let me guess: are you running it from the python shell and editing the file in parallel?

Comment: Is your dictionary structure proper ? It looks to me there is a closing brace missing. Also when you are accessing the CODON_DICT from command line there is an extra closing brace in the end. Does not look like a dictionary.

Comment: @sid, messed it up while copypasting to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms imply that the story went like this:

1. you wrote the file and saved it;
2. you ran the Python shell;
3. you found that `CODON_DICT` can't be accessed just like that and fixed that;
4. you tried that call again within the same Python shell and got that error.

That happens because Python is still using the old version of the module, which is loaded during the import. Although it shows the line from the new file, since all it has in the memory is the bytecode with metadata and has to refer to the disk when error happens. If you want to pick your latest changes without restarting the shell, run:

```
>>> reload(codon_usage)
```

and try again.

(A sidenote: `dict` has no method `deepcopy`, that function comes from the module `copy`. `dict.copy` is enough here, though).